# flutter Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ACTIVITY_NOT_FOUND, No Activity found to handle intent

Tags: flutter, dart, android-activity, launch, tel

In my flutter app, I use a GestureDetector with `await` to make the following call:

```
launchUrl(Uri.parse(url));
```

While the url is `tel:00`

I put this in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="com.dsociety.activities.MyBrowser" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.scytec.datamobile.vd.gui.android.AppPreferenceActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

I have this error in the log

```
 Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ACTIVITY_NOT_FOUND, No Activity found to handle intent { tell:00 }, null, null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest ...>
    <queries>
      <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
      </intent>
    </queries>
...
```

Read carefully the documentation at https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

UPDATE:

The problem is a typo in your link (`tell` instead of `tel`)

Comment: didn't work .. still the same error

Comment: Wait, i see that your error contains this: { tell:00 }

Notice the extra "l" in the "tel" word ("tell" and not "tel")

It seems that your link contains that error. Remove an "l" and try again

Comment: you are right, thanks a lot dear, and please update your answer, keep old one and edit it with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, adding `https://` to the link fixed it.