# Flutter url_launcher hangs after browser opens

Tags: flutter, dart, android-manifest, url-launcher

I'm having a problem launching URLs from my Flutter app on Android emulator. I've scaled it back to a minimal example of my problem is this:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await launchUrl(Uri.parse('https://www.google.com'));
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

When I click the floating action button, the browser opens using the proper url, but then it hangs. It doesn't finish loading, and the emulator itself becomes unresponsive, and I have to shut it down and restart it. I've tried in release and debug mode, but it's the same result. It might be a problem with my AndroidManifest.xml file, but I haven't been able find the correct combination. I have the following line included:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and I've included different intents and filters, such as the examples given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157490/android-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-error-how-it-will-resolve), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75690046/flutter-unhandled-exception-platformexceptionactivity-not-found-no-activity-f), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65883844/flutter-url-launcher-is-not-launching-url-in-release-mode). But I keep getting the same problem. I assume it's probably something dumb I'm missing, but if anyone has any suggestions, I would be appreciative.

Comment: Try removing the `await` before `launchUrl` It should make emulator responsive.

Comment: And about browser hanging, check that emulator is connected to the internet, maybe try opening url directly by opening chrome app manually and try navigating to the url.